# App starts after phone reset

Tags: android, service, reset

I've seen that some apps only start working after a phone reset. Usually are apps that will run silent on the phone. The first time they run they'll ask for some info or prefs. How does those guys do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

These "apps" running at startup are basically `Service`s that the Android framework invokes on startup. If you want your app to be invoked at startup.

Instead of `Service`, you could also call an `Activity`
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

BTW, a similar question was posted [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/). To avoid your question being blocked/closed, it's best to follow the [guidelines here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about doing a gps tracker app. Wouldn't be better to have a Service instead of Activity?

Comment: Thanks. Tell me something, if the service is running how can I access to the preferences since this as no GUI?

Comment: Sure, you could use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().

Comment: But how can i call it to show up. I mean is there a combination of key presses or something? I imagine the first time the service starts I can show the preferences and the service then continues to do what's supposed to do in the background. So how can I access the preferences again? Sorry if I'm bothering you with this stuff.